# Trivial angular test for a beginner

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to do unit testing with angular js but it's not easy.

I want to proceed a simple trivial test like this :

```
describe('Edition Controllers', function(){
  beforeEach(module('DOPCjsControllers.controller'));


it('should check a simple test', inject(function($controller) {
  var scope = {};
  var editionCtrl = $controller('EditionController', {$scope : scope} );
  expect(scope.test).toBe("lol");

   }));
});
```

My controller's begining :

```
'use strict';
/* Controllers */

var DOPCjsControllers = angular.module('DOPCjsControllers', []);

/**
*EditionController : Controlleur de gestion de la partie edition du logiciel.
*/
DOPCjsControllers.controller('EditionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$filter', '$modal','$fileUploader', 'AUTH_EVENTS','NotificationFactory', 'NOTIF_STATUTS','Session','AuthService','$location',
function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $filter, $modal, $fileUploader, AUTH_EVENTS, NotificationFactory, NOTIF_STATUTS, Session, AuthService, $location){
    $scope.test = "lol";
    $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function(event){
        //alert("Connectez vous d'abord");
        console.log("notAuthenticated");

    }); etc ...
```

When i execute the test i see : 
Firefox 29.0.0 (Ubuntu): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.645 secs / 0.011 secs)
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/home/lionnel/angular-seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js".
Firefox 29.0.0 (Ubuntu) Edition Controllers should check a simple test FAILED
    minErr/<@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78
    loadModules/<@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810
    forEach@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323
    loadModules@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775
    createInjector@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715
    workFn@/home/lionnel/angular-seed/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142

do you know what's the trick ?

Thanks for your help

Unfortunately when i write :

```
describe('Edition Controllers', function(){
beforeEach(module('DOPCjsControllers'));


    it('should check a simple test', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {};
      var editionCtrl = $controller('EditionController', {$scope : scope} );
      expect(scope.test).toBe("lol");

    }));
});
```

i have this error message :
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams

Comment: You might need to manually trigger a digest cycle in the test. Try putting scope.$digest(); before the call to expect. Oh...you might also want to inject $rootScope, and create the test scope with $rootScope.$new();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test tries to load a module named "DOPCjsControllers.controller". You don't have any such module. The module you're defining is called "DOPCjsControllers":

```
var DOPCjsControllers = angular.module('DOPCjsControllers', []);
        That's the name of the module ----^
```